# Ember - Custom adapter and serializer for multiple models

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am using RESTAdapter and RESTSerializer for integrating rest service in my ember project. I am able to do the rest service operation with the default ApplicationAdapter(Extend RESTAdapter) and I am able to create custom adapter for specific models.

I want to create a custom adapter which can be used for some specific set of models.

example,

```
//Application adapter extends RESTAdapter

var LookupAdapter = ApplicationAdapter.extend({
   host: Properties.LookupServiceHost,
   namespace : Properties.LookupServiceNamespace,
});

export default LookupAdapter;
```

I have some models like **country, language** etc. For fetching and populating data in data store, now I am using separate adapter, serializer(for handling request, response) for each model. I want those specific models to be worked with **LookupAdapter**. Can we assign this adapter to model anyway so that these models will use the LookupAdapter/LookupSerializer?

Is there a way to tell model that your Adapter is LookupAdapter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create Adapters and Serializers for every model and import your LookupAdapter / -Serializer and extend from it. Non tested code ahead:

```
// In file ../adapters/country.js
import LookupAdapter from '../adapters/lookup';
export default LookupAdapter.extend({});
```

I think you could even omit the `.extend({})`.

EDIT:

If you do not want to create an adapter and serializer for each model you could implement your own `DS.Store`. `DS.Store` provides these methods:

- adapterFor
- serializerFor

You could write a mapping table, which maps the `modelName` to an adapter you specify.

In addition, the ember.js source code says, that when no adapter is found `ApplicationAdapter` is used instead.

EDIT 2:

You could do something like this:

app/mappings/adapters.js:

```
export default {
  'country': 'lookup',
  'city': 'lookup'
}
```

app/stores/application.js:

```
import adaptersMapping from '../mappings/adapters';

export default DS.Store.extend({
  adapterFor(modelName) {
    if(adaptersMapping[modelName]) {
      return this._super(adaptersMapping[modelName]);
    }
    return this._super(modelName);
  }
});
```

Comment: Right now I am creating separate adapter/Serializer for each models by extending LookupAdapter. I am asking like instead of creating separate adapter/serializer, can we use LookupAdapter for each models? Is there a way to tell model that your Adapter is LookupAdapter?

Comment: Thanks Timm for the reply,     adapterFor(model) returns the instance of adapter for that model(currently it returns ApplicationAdapter) . For returning that instance of cutom Adapter we should assign the model to an adpater. I am asking how can we achieve that? I am not clear about mapping table, how can we create that?

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked, but the file path is app/services/store.js. I am editing your answer :)